# Why on('changeDate') function return two result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I have this code (datepicker without Jquery UI)

```
$('#calendar').datepicker().on('changeDate', function (ev) {
    alert('Input changed');
});
```

and when i ran it, it alert ('Input changed') when it supposedly ran only once. Please enlighten me in this issue, it impact my whole code so much.

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what's happening? Is it firing many times?

Comment: it is firing twice. when i ran the whole code, it ran once. but when i clicked on the calendar to change the current week, the code ran twice.

Comment: We need more JavaScript code.

Comment: Which datepicker library you are using? From where you came to know that your datepicker supports `changeDate` event?

Comment: v1.6.4, and it ran nicely, when i want change date, it change date. but when i try to ran this function, it ran twice instead of once

Comment: What is the datepicker version you use? In the past there were quite a few bugs found with regard to this event.

Comment: * Datepicker for Bootstrap v1.6.4 (https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker)

Answer (score 1):

You should use onSelect to get the selected date. 
[Here is a working JSfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/YbLnj/)

```
$("#dt").datepicker({
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    var date = $(this).val();
    var time = $('#time').val();
    alert('on select triggered');
    $("#start").val(date + time.toString(' HH:mm').toString());

}
```

});

Comment: thanks but i cant run this in my code. im trying to include my code now

Comment: Can you provide some code snippet where you are trying to integrate this? May be you need to change the IDs of html elements

Comment: I added some code in my question. please pardon me, i dont know how to add in jsfiddle and import jquery inside. I am so sorry